# Windows drivers - shared memory from user mode->kernel mode

Tags: windows, memory, driver, drivers

I'm messing around with some driver development and I'm having an issue getting some of my code to work. I'm not sure if it's a quirk with the API that I'm unaware of or what.

I have a user app that has created a named shared object under BaseNamedObjects with CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile, etc. I'm trying to read this shared object inside of my driver code using ZwOpenSection and ZwMapViewOfSection

The problem code is below:

```
char *sharedData = NULL;
SIZE_T vs = 256;

InitializeObjectAttributes(&myAttributes,&sectionName,OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,NULL,NULL);
ZwOpenSection(&sectionHandle,SECTION_MAP_READ,&myAttributes)

ZwMapViewOfSection(&sectionHandle, ZwGetCurrentProcess(), (PVOID *)sharedData, 0, 256, 
NULL, &vs, ViewUnmap, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

The call to ZwOpenSection completes successfully and I get the object properly, but the second call fails. The status returned says it's an issue with the ninth parameter, but I've tried every combination I could think of with nothing to show for it, so I'm not sure if it's an issue with a different parameter causing the 9th to be "incorrect" or if I'm missing something else

Thanks.

Comment: MEM_COMMIT is not allowed, MEM_RESERVE makes no sense.  Use 0 here.

Answer (score 1):

Is the access permission with which the section was created the same as the one you have passed here?

MEM_COMMIT is not allowed in a direct call in this function. If you still want to commit and reserve pages, try calling the virtualalloc(), otherwise just pass NULL in the 8th parameter.